# On ranks of finite element matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T=\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_t\}$ be a set of distinct integers.

If $A\in T^{n\times m}$ is an $n\times m$ matrix with entries from $T$ then

> does $rank_{\Bbb R_+}A=rank_{\Bbb Q_+}A$ hold true?

Comment: I understand you mean the notion of nonnegative rank in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_rank_(linear_algebra) (it's not so standard, I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's true. The inequality $\le$ is trivial. For the nontrivial inequality, we have some family of nonnegative rational vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ (by nonnegative vectors I mean with nonnegative coefficients, I apology to use this poor and absurd English terminology), we assume that there exist nonnegative real vectors $w_1,\dots,w_d$ such that for every $i$, we can write $v_i=\sum_j\lambda_{ij}w_j$ with $\lambda_{ij}$.

We consider this as a system of unknowns (all $\lambda_{ij}$ and all coefficients of the $w_j$ being unknowns), with the linear conditions $v_i=\sum_j\lambda_{ij}w_j$ and the inequalities saying that all these unknowns are nonnegative. This is a system with rational coefficients. Hence it defines a rational polyhedron. Since it has a real point, it has a rational point. Hence we can find $d$ nonnegative rational vectors such that every $v_i$ is a nonnegative rational combination of those.